# Git Tracking RPM files associated with a project

Tags: git

Using GIT what is the best way to track binary RPM files in a project where the filename changes with each version?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. You have RPM files in your source tree and you want to track them with Git? What's wrong with simply tracking them like any other file? (Having RPMs in your source repository is likely a code smell, but I'll assume you have a good reason for doing this.)

Comment: I am working with a pre-existing repo.  The RPMs are required to support the associated application source tree.  They are applied to a baseline installation. Captured in Git for convenience I assume, there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Chris was commented, you'll simply add you RPM files for each commit and when the filename changes with each version use git mv

```
git mv old_file new_file
```

This will inform git that the file name has changed

Comment: In the past this was handled by deleting the old version of the RPM and adding the new version.  I have been doing what you suggested; using git mv to move the old RPM to the new versions filename then overwriting the file with the new version of the RPM.  This preserves the the history of the file.  I was just thinking there might be an easier or more standard way of handling this.

Comment: There is literally no difference between `git rm`ing the old file then `git add`ing the new one and `git mv` then overwriting. Git doesn't track renames; it *detects* them based on content. In both cases, if the files are similar enough Git will detect the rename. In both cases, if the files are very different Git will not detect the rename.